# How to add Cache-Control on create-react app

Tags: javascript, caching, browser, create-react-app, cache-control

so I was reading this article [how to add control-cache](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/cache-control.html)

and I think the best way to do it is via `.htaccess` file, but will it work on create-react-app if I add it? I've read that that file is only working on Apache (and I think we are not using Apache) - I am not a devops guy or someone that knows how deployment or server works so It's quite hard for me to understand (I have no idea how we deploy, another team is handling it :( ).

So, how do I properly add it on create-react-app so I can cache my static images?

I saw a couple of the same questions here but they don't have an answer.

Comment: [" Set up your favorite HTTP server so that a visitor to your site is served `index.html`"](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/). See the documentation for whichever HTTP server you select.

Comment: Here how you can do cache control using the origin or your CDN, in this case it's CloudFront: https://dev.to/mnathani/how-to-cache-frontend-app-1kkj